# Why do I get null pointer exception: null when getting value from view with form url encoded?

Tags: java, playframework, nullpointerexception, forms

I am coding in Java/html-scala in the Play framework.

I am trying to get a value from my view using form url encoded but all I get is null pointer exception.
In my controller, I do:

```
String[] searchTag= request().body().asFormUrlEncoded().get("questionTag"); //this is where I get my null pointer exception
//questionTag is the name of my input field in the view
```

In my view:
At the top of my view, I have:

```
@helper.form(action=routes.TeacherController.ValidateQuestion(), 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data", 'class -> "form-horizontal") {... //rest of my code
```

my input field:

```
<input name="questionTag" class="input-xxlarge">
```

In the same view, I allow the user to upload a file and I get that file in the same function in the controller with:

```
Http:MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart attachment = body.getFile("attachment");
```

I was wondering if that might be causing this exception, that I can not get data with both kinds of methods (multipart/form-data and `asFormUrlEncoded().get("questionTag"))` in the same view?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, friend! ;)

You only need a little bit modification on your code. Because you define the form as `multipart/form-data`, you should handle in the controller like following:

```
// get all request content as MultipartFormData
Http.MultipartFormData formData = request().body().asMultipartFormData();

// get the form data
Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart attachment = formData.getFile("attachment");
String[] searchTag = formData.asFormUrlEncoded().get("questionTag"); // works!!
```

Notice that, on `formData` variable, there is such method called `asFormUrlEncoded()` too. It will **extract the data part** from your `multipart-form`.

Not to be confused with method `RequestBody.asFormUrlEncoded()` because the API says, it is used to **parsing the request content** as URL form-encoded.

I hope, the API reference below may used for your reference:

1. [`RequestBody` API Docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.1/java/play/mvc/Http.RequestBody.html)
2. [`MultipartFormData` API Docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.1/java/play/mvc/Http.MultipartFormData.html)

Good luck!